# T* and const T*

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constants

I believe this may apply to many T's, but I know for sure this applies to integers. As part of learning  C++, I am trying to explain the following behavior in terms of the language in the standard.

```
typedef const int * constintptr;
typedef int * intptr;

intptr p;
constintptr cp = p;
const constintptr& crcp = p;
//constintptr & rcp = p;
```

From looking at n3337, sec 8.5.3.  It seems this behavior is explained by saying that int* is convertible to a const int * prvalue, but is not reference compatible. (correct me if I am wrong).

I see that this is desirable behavior (or we could subvert the const), and the desirability of this behavior is not what this question is about.

The question is  where in the standard it is specified (or implied) that they intptr and constintptr are not reference-compatible.

Comment: I think that's pretty straight-forward: `p` is not a value of type `constintptr`. You can *convert* it, which gives a temporary, and thus an rvalue, but the rvalue doesn't bind to the lvalue reference.

Comment: The only things that are reference compatible are things like derived classes in some common inheritance hierarchy, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same section, 8.5.3/4 (numbering from in n3797, which I have available) defines reference-compatible:

> Given types “*cv1* `T1`” and “*cv2* `T2`,” “*cv1* `T1`” is *reference-related*
>   to “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is the same type as `T2` , or `T1` is a base class of
>   `T2` . “*cv1* `T1`” is *reference-compatible* with “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is
>   reference-related to `T2` and *cv1* is the same cv-qualification as, or
>   greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*

So you have type T1 is `int*` and T2 `int const*`. They are not the same type. Neither one of them is a base class of the other (because neither is a class at all). Therefore, they are not reference-related.

When the standard says "cv1 T1", it means any type that is a result of applying 0 or more of `const`, `volatile` to the type `T1`. It *does not* mean textual substitution, that is to say it does not mean any type that is declared by 0 or more of the keywords `const`, `volatile` followed by another sequence of tokens which is a type declaration for T1.

So it's possible that you've misunderstood this such that you think `const int*` is a cv-qualified version of `int*`. If it were, then under the general rule they would be reference-related and so there would need to be text in the standard to make an exception. But it is not. `int *const` is a cv-qualified version of `int*`.

Comment: My question is, basically, does the standard mention that int* and int const* (or other types) are not under any special sort of relation other than conversion?

Comment: @orm: you mean, is there a separate section in the standard that says, "as a consequence of the definition in 8.5.3, the following pairs of types are not reference-related:" followed by a whole list of examples including "`const int*` and `int*`". I doubt it. The standard does contain examples to illustrate its rules, but other than that it's redundant to state particular cases that are already covered by the definition.

Comment: Not as a consequence of 8.5.3, just in general. Here's what I mean. In your reasoning: "They are not the same type. Neither one of them is a base class of the other."  The sentence that they are not base class of each other, where is that fact coming from. I see how you don't want that. But is that specified?  Is it from the fact that they are not classes? is it from the fact that unless it says they are related, then they aren't?

Comment: @orm: yes, they are not class types and therefore certainly one is not a base of the other. You are also correct that if the definition of "related" doesn't say they're related, then they are not related. That's what a definition means. Italic text (which come to think of it got lost when I copied and pasted this quote) when describing a technical term signifies a definition in the standard.

Comment: ah. Thanks. Thats the understanding I wanted to get to.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Re "they are not class types and therefore certainly one is not a base of the other", very little can be assumed about the formal terminology, where words do not always mean what they sound like. For example, in the same vein as "base" one might thing that "most derived" necessarily requires class type, so if it's not class type is certainly not that, yes? However, in C++11 §1.8/4 one finds that "an object of a most derived class type or of a non-class type is called a most derived object". Being most derived does not, formally, imply any base, or even class type... Just sayin'.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: true. If I was writing a formal proof of my statements, using the standard as a set of axioms, then I would have to write more. It is true that only class types (including structs) have bases or can be bases, but I haven't supported that from the standard.